# How do i dynamically set the `html` style?

Tags: javascript

This is a very simple one which I have never ran into before.

Depending on the context of the page, if the app is running directly, it should take the browser window height but otherwise it should be `auto`.

Just imagine for now that I don't have 2 context.  Just 1.  Direct.  In that case, this following CSS would do what I want.

```
html, body { 
   height: 100%
}
```

So perhaps, lets take it further, and make it a class so we can go back to the optional support of both contexts.

```
.fit { 
   height: 100%
}
```

I am aware I could do `element.classlist.add('fit')` on elements including the `document.body`.  However for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do that with the `window` which I presume `html{}` rule refers to.

How do I set a class (or a direct style) dynamically in this instance?

Comment: html is not window, and you have zero reason to ever put styles on the html element since only body content ever gets rendered. That's why there _is_ a body element to begin with (to distinguish it from header markup that should _not_ get rendered in any way). Set your class on body and leave html itself out of your CSS, and things should work just fine. As for "height: 100%", that's probably not what you meant at all. You probably meant `body { height: 100vh; }` because height % is relative to the body. By definition, they are 100% no matter how short or long their content is.

Comment: I am not sure @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

if I remove `html{}` from my style sheet, the `html` is not 100% height, so it is definitely having an effect.

Comment: So your container should just be using 100% of it's available height?

Comment: If you want a single page app look, then set `body { position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }` and now you have an "always perfectly constrained to the viewport" document. The `html` element itself should not need styling.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I appreciate your prompt and factual response.  Thank you.